# how to shrink consecutive B ip classes in bigger one

Tags: ip, firewall

After reading [List of IP Space used by Facebook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11164672/850781):

"Real" list is the last answer, but I wonder how Igy (with the answer marked as solution) managed to shrink the list a lot by adding consecutive classes into a bigger one (by decreasing accordingly from network mask for each new consecutive network), is there a tool, or only manually ?

This is a HUGE improvement for firewall, where number of rules counts (the shorter the better).

Answer (score 3):

A simple solution is to use [netaddr](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
import netaddr
ips = netaddr.IPSet()
for addr in all_addrs:
    ips.add(addr)
ips.compact()
for cidr in ips.iter_cidrs():
    print(str(cidr))
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Python 3 script can do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from functools import reduce
import sys

def add_mark(regions, mark, k):
    r = regions[:]
    i = 0
    j = len(r)
    while i < j:
        m = (i + j) // 2
        if mark < r[m][0]:
            j = m
        elif r[m][0] < mark:
            i = m + 1
        else:
            r[m][1] += k
            if r[m][1] == 0:
                del r[m]
            return r
    r.insert(i, [mark, k])
    return r

def add_region(regions, start, end):
    return add_mark(add_mark(regions, start, 1), end, -1)

def parse_network(n):
    pos = n.find('/')
    return ip_to_int(n[:pos]), 2**(32 - int(n[pos+1:]))

def ip_to_int(ip):
    return reduce(lambda a, b: 256*a + b, map(int, ip.split('.')))

def print_summary(r):
    if len(r) == 0:
        return
    start = None
    level = 0
    for item in r:
        level += item[1]
        if start is None:
            start = item[0]
        elif level == 0:
            summarize_networks(start, item[0])
            start = None

def summarize_networks(start, end):
    while start < end:
        mask = 32
        amount = 1
        while start % amount == 0 and start + amount - 1< end:
            mask -= 1
            amount *= 2
        mask += 1
        amount //= 2
        print('{0}/{1}'.format(int_to_ip(start), mask))
        start += amount

def int_to_ip(n):
    n, o4 = divmod(n, 256)
    n, o3 = divmod(n, 256)
    o1, o2 = divmod(n, 256)
    return '.'.join(map(str, [o1, o2, o3, o4]))

def main():
    regions = []
    while True:
        line = sys.stdin.readline()
        if len(line) == 0:
            break
        for item in line.strip().split():
            start, amount = parse_network(item)
            regions = add_region(regions, start, start + amount)
    print_summary(regions)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Example:

```
./unique_networks.py <<EOF
192.168.0.0/24
192.168.0.128/25
192.168.0.248/30
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.100.0/24
EOF
192.168.0.0/23
192.168.100.0/24
```

For a facebook's list of

```
204.15.20.0/22
69.63.176.0/20
66.220.144.0/20
66.220.144.0/21
69.63.184.0/21
69.63.176.0/21
74.119.76.0/22
69.171.255.0/24
173.252.64.0/18
69.171.224.0/19
69.171.224.0/20
103.4.96.0/22
69.63.176.0/24
173.252.64.0/19
173.252.70.0/24
31.13.64.0/18
31.13.24.0/21
66.220.152.0/21
66.220.159.0/24
69.171.239.0/24
69.171.240.0/20
31.13.64.0/19
31.13.64.0/24
31.13.65.0/24
31.13.67.0/24
31.13.68.0/24
31.13.69.0/24
31.13.70.0/24
31.13.71.0/24
31.13.72.0/24
31.13.73.0/24
31.13.74.0/24
31.13.75.0/24
31.13.76.0/24
31.13.77.0/24
31.13.96.0/19
31.13.66.0/24
173.252.96.0/19
69.63.178.0/24
31.13.78.0/24
31.13.79.0/24
31.13.80.0/24
31.13.82.0/24
31.13.83.0/24
31.13.84.0/24
31.13.85.0/24
31.13.86.0/24
31.13.87.0/24
31.13.88.0/24
31.13.89.0/24
31.13.90.0/24
31.13.91.0/24
31.13.92.0/24
31.13.93.0/24
31.13.94.0/24
31.13.95.0/24
69.171.253.0/24
69.63.186.0/24
31.13.81.0/24
179.60.192.0/22
179.60.192.0/24
179.60.193.0/24
179.60.194.0/24
179.60.195.0/24
185.60.216.0/22
45.64.40.0/22
185.60.216.0/24
185.60.217.0/24
185.60.218.0/24
185.60.219.0/24
129.134.0.0/16
157.240.0.0/16
204.15.20.0/22
69.63.176.0/20
69.63.176.0/21
69.63.184.0/21
66.220.144.0/20
69.63.176.0/20
```

networks this script summarizes them to:

```
31.13.24.0/21
31.13.64.0/18
45.64.40.0/22
66.220.144.0/20
69.63.176.0/20
69.171.224.0/19
74.119.76.0/22
103.4.96.0/22
129.134.0.0/16
157.240.0.0/16
173.252.64.0/18
179.60.192.0/22
185.60.216.0/22
204.15.20.0/22
```

Answer (score 1):

With the assistance of [sds](https://stackoverflow.com/users/850781/sds)'s answer, which showcased the beauty of `netaddr`,  I devised the following solution to convert Facebook IP ranges to `ipset`:

```bash
ipset create facebook4 hash:net comment
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | awk '/^route:/ {print $2}' | ./netaddr-compact.py | sed 's/^/ipset add facebook4 /' | sh -x
ipset create facebook6 hash:net family inet6 comment
whois -h whois.radb.net -- '-i origin AS32934' | awk '/^route6:/ {print $2}' | ./netaddr-compact.py | sed 's/^/ipset add facebook6 /' | sh -x
ipset create facebook list:set comment
ipset add facebook facebook4
ipset add facebook facebook6
```

The `netaddr-compact.py` file is straightforward:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38099023

import fileinput

import netaddr  # on ubuntu: apt install python3-netaddr

ips = netaddr.IPSet()
for addr in fileinput.input():
    ips.add(addr)
ips.compact()
for cidr in ips.iter_cidrs():
    print(str(cidr))
```

Additionally, starting from **Python 3.3**, it is possible to compact (collapse) IP networks using the [`ipaddress`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/ipaddress.html) stdlib module, eliminating the need for an additional module installation:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/38099023

import fileinput
import ipaddress

networks = [ipaddress.ip_network(network.rstrip()) for network in fileinput.input()]
for network in ipaddress.collapse_addresses(networks):
    print(str(network))
```

Edit: The code above encounters a `TypeError: 2400:cb00:233::/48 and 172.69.188.0/24 are not of the same version`, when the input contains both IPv4 and IPv6 addresses. In such cases, it is necessary to handle IPv4 and IPv6 separately:

```py
import fileinput
import ipaddress

networks = {}
for line in fileinput.input():
    ip_network = ipaddress.ip_network(line.strip())
    version = ip_network.version
    networks.setdefault(version, []).append(ip_network)
for version in networks:
    aggregated_networks = ipaddress.collapse_addresses(networks[version])
    print(*aggregated_networks, sep="\n")
```